# PowerDNS works only on local

Tags: linux, firewall, dig, powerdns

So. The PowerDNS 3.3 as salve works only on local.
(Also there is a nginx which works fine)

This work good

```
dig example.com A @127.0.0.1
```

But this not (slave server)

```
dig example.com A @ns2.example.com
;; global options: +cmd
;; connection timed out; no servers could be reached
```

I've tried with IP of ns2.example.com, but no good result anything.

Where the problem might be?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

There was a problem in pdns-recursor config.

So, you need write your real IP address OR 0.0.0.0 instead of 127.0.0.1 in
local-address property.

Answer (score -1):

`netstat -nao | grep 53` will help you.

You listen not at all local interfaces of filter DNS-port (TCP and UDP 53)

Comment: How to start listen? There is a string            
            
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:53            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN  
off (0.00/0/0)  
  
udp        0      0 127.0.0.1:53            0.0.0.0:*  
off (0.00/0/0)

Comment: @KirillBurkhanov - it will be second question, and not for SO (offtopic here), but for SU|SF

Comment: I mean, what the problem of it? Because other strings have real IP address, and this only local.